# C++ findwindow with traditional chinese character

Tags: c++, findwindow

I having difficult on findwindow function when met Chinese language;

```
HWND hwnd = 0;

do {
   printf("searching...");
   hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "chineseWindowName");
 }while (hwnd == NULL);

 printf("\n\nFound!!\n");
```

the Chinese name can't be found so always stuck on searching, what better way to solve this or is there a way to get the window name (not process name, process name is "helan.exe", I try but failed, process name is different with window title name);

how can we look for correct window name and make it work in code?
the Chinese is traditional;

Comment: You probably should be searching in Unicode, not ANSI.

Comment: hello Raymond can you give me example because after you reply i search untill now still can't figure out how...